# $\min_{b}E(X-b)^2=E(X-EX)^2$

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite means.

I showed that $$\min_{g}E(Y-g(X))^2=E(Y-E(Y|X))^2$$ where $g$ ranges over all functions.

In the book it says that $$\min_{b}E(X-b)^2=E(X-EX)^2$$ can be derived as a special case of the above.

Unfortunately I can't see how, so I would appreciate it if someone could explain this. Thanks!

Comment: In your expression, choose $X$ to be a constant valued random variable (i.e., with a dirac delta distribution). Then any function of it is necessarily also some (possibly different) constant. Further, note that $X$ is measurable w.r.t. the trivial sigma-algebra, and thus this is also the sigma algebra generated by $X$. But then $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$. You immediately get that $\min_{b} \mathbb{E}[(Y-b)^2] = \mathbb{E}( (Y - \mathbb{E}[Y])^2]$.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Edit: Sorry I misread your post. But are you sure that there is no square on the left hand side of the first equation?</strike>

If you interchange $X$ and $Y$ in the statement you showed (which can be done as they both are random variables without any further assumptions) you get

$$\min_{g}E(X-g(Y))^2=E(X-E(X|Y))^2.$$

Now use a special $Y$, namely a constant random variable, say $Y=1$. Then you get

$$\min_{g}E(X-g(1))^2=E(X-EX)^2.$$

But $g(1)$ is just a value and if you range over all functions $g$ you can just range over all values and name them $b$.

$$\min_{b}E(X-b)^2=E(X-EX)^2.$$

Comment: True, I forgot it

Comment: And because constant $Y$ is $\mathcal F_0:=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$-measurable we have $\sigma(Y)=\mathcal F_0$ and therefore $E(X|Y)=E(X)$?

Comment: Exactly. The random variable $X|Y$ is basically a mean of the value of $X$ over all the sets where $Y$ is constant. 

Or more intuitively, we look for the value of $X$ under the assumption that $Y=i$ where $i$ is some value. But as $Y$ is constant our assumption does not give us any information actually. So the expectation of $X$ does not change.